# Restore attributes after losing session JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, httprequest

I have a page in jsp(search page) using some differents combos. I trying to restore the search attributes in case of losing the session. How is the best way to do it? Save the attributes in cookies in the request?

Answer (score 1):

you can save the attributes in cookies and request both but request scope is limited and cookies access whole application so i prefer cookies.